# How to match a url from a list of patterns in a textfile?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a text file that contains meta-urls in the following form:

```
http://www.xyz.com/.*services/
http://www.xyz.com/.*/wireless
```

I want to compare all the patterns from that file with my URL, and execute an action if I find a match. This matching process is hard to understand for me.

Assuming splitarray[0] contains the first line of text file:

```
            String url = page.getWebURL().getURL();         
            URL url1 = new URL(url);
```

how can we compare url1 with splitarray[0]?

**UPDATED**

```
BufferedReader readbuffer = null;
        try {
            readbuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filters.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String strRead;


        try {
            while ((strRead=readbuffer.readLine())!=null){
                String splitarray[] = strRead.split(",");
                String firstentry = splitarray[0];
                String secondentry = splitarray[1];
                String thirdentry = splitarray[2];
                //String fourthentry = splitarray[3];
                //String fifthentry = splitarray[4];
                System.out.println(firstentry + " " + secondentry+ " " +thirdentry);
                URL url1 = new URL("http://www.xyz.com/ship/reach/news-and");

                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http://www.xyz.com/.*/reach");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(url1.toString());

                if (m.matches()) {
                  //Do whatever
                    System.out.println("Yes Done");
                }



                }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Matching is working fine... But if I want that any url which start with the pattern giving in the splitarray[0] then do this... how we can implement this... As in the above case it is not matching but this url `http://www.xyz.com/ship/w` is from this pattern only `http://www.xyz.com/.*/reach` So any url that starts with this pattern.. just do this thing in the if loop... Any suggestions will be appreciated...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused as to where the regexes are coming from.  The text file?  In any case, you'll have a hard time comparing `url1` to any regexes because it's a `URL` object, and regex compares strings.  So you'll want to stick with your `String url` instead.

Try this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(splitarray[0]);
Matcher m = p.matcher(url);

if (m.matches()) {
  //Do whatever
}
```

The `m.matches()` method checks whether the entire String you provide matches the pattern, which is probably what you want here.  If you need to check whether part of your String matches, use `m.find()` instead.

**Update**

Since you're only looking to match the pattern at the beginning of the String, you'll want to use `m.find()` instead.  The special character `^` only matches at the beginning of a String, so add that to the front of your regex, e.g.:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^" + splitarray[0]);
```

etc.

Comment: Maybe you'd consider accepting my answer since it fixed your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a step here. You first need to translate your URLs to a regular expression, or design a method to use those URLs, then only can you compare your URL url1 to those patterns.

Based on the patterns you have shown, I assume you are designing software for a xyz solution, like their routers. Therefore, your URLs probably fall in a simple pattern style, like
    http://www.xyz.com/**regular-expression-here**